# Shared tools always getting lost

Tags: company-policy, efficiency

I'm part of a small team of datacenter worker drones, and we're constantly wasting time hunting for tools because we can't find what we need.

In the case of some tools, I've just taken to buying literally 20 times as many as we need so that we can find them faster.  But I can't do that for all of them.

Many are too expensive to buy one for every person and charge them for lost tools like I understand automotive shops sometimes do.  We don't have personal lockers or space to install lockers, nor space for complete duplicates of all tools (one copy per employee) either.

What policies or procedures can we try, to reduce misplaced tools and the time wasted therefrom?

Comment: So, you have tools but no place to store them? Where do you leave them after use? Do you have an inventory? Who else could have access to your working area that could have taken them?

Comment: @DarkCygnus Who said that?                and In the correct place of course.

Comment: Are these tools permanently lost, or do you eventually find them?

Comment: uhmm.... you did... in your post... thus why I was asking for clarification: *"We don't have lockers or space for that either."*

Comment: How come the, you "dont have space for that" but you also leave them in "the correct place"?

Comment: @sf02  they do usually turn up.  Just not when needed.  I think the rate of theft is pretty low.  I'm more concerned about time lost each day.  probably close to an hour on average, wandering around in dispair, searching.  I daydream about some sort of locker that can only be opened by leaving your car keys inside, and won't return them until the items are returned.

Comment: @DarkCygnus the 'that' which we don't have space for is indivudalized personal lockers, and duplicating all of our tool inventory.  I have edited the question to remove the pronoun.  We have space to store our existing tools.  There is shelving.

Comment: This probably belongs more on https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I don't understand why this should be on life hacks? Because of the "theories/reading on the topic of time-efficient organization" part? I think that part should just be edited out since it's a different question than the main issue.

Comment: A comment by the OP from apparently another account that was stuck as a suggested edit to the question: *One answer mentiones an alarm if not returned for 10 minutes: Can you provide an example of an alarm style system?  I am particularly interested in something like electronic lockers for tools that do not open without a thumbbrint/photo of who opens them, and then their face and what they took stays on a public screen until it's returned.*

Comment: @BSMP I think life hacks because this seems to be a question about how to track tools in an inventive manner, not in a typical fashion. The fact this is in a workplace is irrelevant to the issue as I see it

Comment: Some companies provide a system using beacons attached to each tool to track them.Track my tools ( https://www.bosch.com/stories/trackmytools/ ) is one such system, but it seems it is only available in France and Germany. You could have a look into it if you are ok with spending some money.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to workplace.SE! I edited to remove your "side-question" about " time-efficient organization". Asking two questions at once does not work well on this site, and your main question is about misplaced tools. Feel free to ask the side-question separately :-).

Answer (score 10):

If there are no consequences for not returning tools, losing tools or stealing tools, why do you expect any worker to return them when simply having them with you when you need them is far more convenient.

You need to setup a policy which makes people return tools to a central location. It doesn't matter if you have a board with the shape of the tools painted in. Or an alarm that triggers if a tool isn't returned after 10 minutes. Or just toolbox or a bunch of draws.

You need to start holding people accountable for the tools that they use. This means keeping track of who takes what. And making them responsible and accountable for returning it.

Some basic ideas

- A sign off sheet which records who takes whan and when. With take and return times
- Someone to manage the tools in general
- A camera to record who takes the tools so you can figure out who to ask when it goes missing

Comment: As a variant on this, give each employee a stack of card with their name on them, and ask them to leave a card in place of each tool they are using.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan all to easy to take a tool and not leave a card... Have to have a tool store controller - this is the only way that works for shared tools.

Comment: @SolarMike any and each of these solutions will need enforcement anyway, and a card is not harder to "forget" than a signature.

Comment: @SolarMike From comments, it appears the tools do usually turn up. Given that, just make it as quick, easy, and convenient as possible to leave a note of who has the tool.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan having done an apprenticeship where there was a controlled tool store with a person issuing the tools and keeping records of who when and how long, I can promise you it works and works well - you know exactly who has what and who breaks it - tools can be expensive. From experience, not comments....

Comment: @SolarMike That the controlled option works is fine and well, but it may not be workable for OP to have a full resource dedicated to securing the store room. Thus, such alternative approaches that make it more likely things work out without such a dedicated solution do make sense and can be helpful even if not being perfect wrt to the reliability scale.

Answer (score 1):

In a small team, it's really hard to create mechanisms to force people to follow policies like "put the tools back when you're done using them." If you were in a big organization. you could have a secure tool room with an attendant to sign them out, but that's a hassle and really only suitable for expensive tools.

You could have locked personal toolboxes under your desks. But then everybody would need their own tools: unworkable.

It sounds like you have a teamwork problem. Certainly teamwork will help solve the missing-tool problem. Can you, or your supervisor, call a friendly problem-solving meeting? The problem is that people can't find the tools they need when they have jobs to do. Have a friendly talk about that problem, not a finger-wagging "you stole the drill!" kind of talk.

Be patient. It takes time for people to adjust to new ways of working together.

Comment: If your answer means that the best solution is to educate the people, then I agree with you.

Comment: Education yes. But also to try to help them care a little more about each others' quality of work life.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Shadowzee's approach of having a central place and a return policy. 
If that however does not pan out for lack of a central place that can easily be monitored with respect to who takes what and who brings what back, there is also a decentralised approach:

**Spread the tool responsibility! Each tool goes to a worker that by default has it**. That worker is responsible to have it back at the end of the day if someone else requests using it. Otherwise he's gonna get X (reprimand, no coffee the next morning, has to bring cake, ....)